# Read data from an array

Tags: php

Hello am new to array can someone help? i have array in array.
how can i get only all the [key] data from the [permissions] array.

```
 Array
(
    [name] => john
    [password] => 150211444
    [permissions] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => 2
                    [moduleId] => 13
                    [permission] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => 3
                    [moduleId] => 13
                    [permission] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [key] => 8
                    [moduleId] => 13
                    [permission] => 1
                )

        )
    )
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP options for extracting data from an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795139/php-options-for-extracting-data-from-an-array)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
$keys = array();
foreach($arr['permissions'] as $key => $value){
    $keys[] = $value["key"]
}
```

and `$keys` is an array that contains all the `[key]` values

Comment: why you dont use $value['key'] in the loop?

Comment: @silly good point, i corrected it

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti cool, but now you have to remove the [$key] part :-)

Answer (score 1):

heres my corrected answer
use constants or variables for the index names and check array-key first with array_key_exists (and not with isset)

```
const INDEX_PERMISSIONS = 'permissions';
const INDEX_KEY = 'key';

$keys = array();
if(true === array_key_exists(INDEX_PERMISSIONS, $array)) {
    $inner = $array[INDEX_PERMISSIONS];
        if(null != $inner && is_array($inner)) {
            foreach($inner as $inner_values) {
                if(null !== $inner_values && is_array($inner_values) && array_key_exists(INDEX_KEY, $inner_values)) {
                $keys[] = $inner_values[INDEX_KEY];
            }
        }   
    }

}
print_r($keys);
```

Comment: +1 for the key-check... hi silly. to the death?

Comment: In this example, `array_keys()` will return  `[key]`, `[moduleId]` and   `[permission]` which is not the OP's intent

Comment: @RobAllen right, i misunderstood the question. is corrected now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know it's always called `permissions` and assuming you are creating a var called `$myArray` to parse through:

```
<?php

 foreach($myArray['permissions'] as $record)
 {


     echo $record['key']; 

 }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function iter($item, $key) {
    echo $key, $item['permission'], PHP_EOL;
}

array_walk($array['permissions'], 'iter');
```